# How to Query for Many to Many Fields in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have these classes -

```
class DocumentType(models.Model):
    type_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField('type name', max_length=200)

class MetaData(models.Model):
    metadata_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    name = models.CharField('metadata name', max_length=200, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField('description')

class DocumentTypeMetaData(models.Model):
    documentType_id = models.ManyToManyField(DocumentType,)
    metadata_id = models.ManyToManyField(MetaData,)
    required = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

For example, a DocumentType value of 'Photo' would have Required Metadata of 'Decade' and 'Orientation'.

In the DocumentTypeMetaData class I would like to have a `def __str__(self)` function that returns something like the following in the admin page -

```
Photo: (Decade, Photo Type) required
```

The format is not critical, I just want to know which metadata is required. Currently, all that is displayed is

```
DocumentTypeMetaData object
```

on the admin page.

I am struggling with how to write the queries for this function.

Thanks!

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These relationships are not right. The many-to-many relationship is between DocumentType and MetaData; DocumentTypeMetaData is the through table. So:

```
class DocumentType(models.Model):
    type_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField('type name', max_length=200)
    metadata = models.ManyToManyField('MetaData', through='DocumentTypeMetaData')

class MetaData(models.Model):
    metadata_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    name = models.CharField('metadata name', max_length=200, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField('description')

class DocumentTypeMetaData(models.Model):
    document_type = models.ForeignKey(DocumentType)
    metadata = models.ForeignKey(MetaData)
    required = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {} {}'.format(self.document_type, self.metadata, self.required)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! It works well. Can you explain the syntax of '{} {} {}'.format(...). Also, for completeness, you may want to remove the extra 'a' in MetaDaata in the 4th line.